# Odd ( ) ( ) C syntax - what does it do

Tags: c

There is the following code declaration:

```
int (*oled_format)(unsigned short F_gfx, unsigned char* oled_data, size_t oled_len, ...);
```

used in situations such as below:

```
format_rc = display_port->dev->oled_format(cmd, oled_data, cmd_len, color);
```

What does this do? Clearly it returns an int, but there does not seem to be any function description outside of the header file.

Googling brought me to some C++ docs about explicit instantiation which are not very clear and sometimes vary syntactically: [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) , and [2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Explicit_instantiation)

Comment: ```oled_format``` is a pointer to a function. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) should be a good overview how those work.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up!

Comment: This could help you in the future, [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*oled_format%29%28unsigned+short%2C+unsigned+char+*%29).

Comment: fixed the first link

Comment: Please note that you've linked to C++ references, but C and C++ are different languages so they _will_ vary syntactically. The C resources already listed are much better references in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the declaration of a function pointer.

For those who are interested, the following StackOverflow answer explains how C's function pointers work:

[How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: May as well include the link from the comment by @sj95126, at least then your answer would link to further information.